# How to declare new type in next js for .lottie

Tags: typescript, next.js13

[image]

I have added the module properly so there is not can't find module error , as my code is working properly too.

But type declarations error is major issue my code not able to recognise the .lottie file.
Have used dotLottie player to run the lottie files.

Please can anyone help me how should i declare new type in next js.

Comment: Working on Next js and it seems i need to declare that .lottie type somehow because it is  working properly otherwise but it not gonna build :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the type declaration in the global `index.d.ts` file. If the file is not present you can add to the where `next.config.js` file is present.

```
declare module "*.lottie";
```